# Disconnect-ExchangeOnline disconnects ExOnline and EMS

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Hallo I have a little problem. I made a script that does some shit in the EMS than connects to toe ExOnline Shell and does some shit there. Both of the commands are running in a Do / While loop. When the loop uses the command `Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -confirm:$false` command it also disconnects the EMS.

Does anyone know a way around that?

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer on Reddit from the user u/mkoch7811

Here it is:

> Use the -Prefix parameter with Connect-ExchangeOnline to add a
> specific prefix to all of the Exchange Online commands, then you'll be
> able to differentiate between online and on-premises commands.
>
> For instance, set -Prefix to "cloud", then Get-Mailbox will go to the
> on-premises Exchange and Get-cloudMailbox will go to Exchange Online.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/connect-exchangeonline?view=exchange-ps#-prefix